# Groups such that the corresponding algebra is central

Tags: abstract-algebra, solution-verification

> Find all groups $G$ such that the corresponding algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ is central

I know that since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed we have: $\mathbb{C}[G]=\prod_{i=1}^sM_{n_s}(\mathbb{C})$ so in order for $\mathbb{C}[G]$ to be central we must have $\mathbb{C}[G]=M_n(\mathbb{C})$. This implies $|G|=n^2$ and $G$ non abelian or $n=1$ which gives us the trivial group. However if $n>1$ we would have a non trivial group with exactly 1 conjugacy class so the group in question is exactly the trivial one. Have I gotten it wrong somewhere?

Comment: I believe you could have worded that a little more clearly, but your logic is perfectly sound.

Comment: What does it mean for an algebra to be *central*?

Comment: @rschwieb It means the center of the algebra is a field

Comment: What's the commutator of an algebra?  It couldn't be the commutator ideal?

Comment: @rschwieb apologies I meant the center edited it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems ok, but if you're sure that it has to be a single matrix ring, it's faster to just note that $M_n(\mathbb C)$ is simple and $\mathbb C[G]$ is only simple when its augmentation ideal is $\{0\}$, meaning $G=\{1\}$.

Comment: I am not familiar with the concept of an "augmentation ideal" though, I'll try to look into it

Comment: The ideal of $\mathbb C[G]$ generated by $\{g-1\mid g\in G\}$? Pretty bread and butter for anyone who handles group algebras...